# PostgreSQL: compare NULL and normal value

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a trigger in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update_func_pk1() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    ri RECORD;
    old_value TEXT;
    new_value TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR ri IN
        SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE
            table_schema = quote_ident('public')
        AND table_name = quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || ri.column_name || '::text' INTO new_value USING NEW;
        EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || ri.column_name || '::text' INTO old_value USING OLD;

        IF new_value <> old_value AND ri.column_name != 'update_by' THEN
            INSERT INTO protokoll(datetime, operation, tabelle, field, pk1, old_value, new_value, update_by)
                   VALUES(now(), TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME, ri.column_name, NEW.cfg, old_value, new_value, NEW.update_by);
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Sometimes if old_value is changed from NULL to normal value (or from normal value to NULL), the condition "new_value <> old_value" is NOT true but unknown. I would like ask, there is a method that I can get true in the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`is distinct from`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

```
if new_value IS DISTINCT FROM old_value and ri.column_name <> 'update_by' then 
   ...
end if;
```